# Вывод unordered_map в виде ячеек хеш-таблицы

Tags: c++, stl

Возможно ли вывести в консоль unordered_map в виде ячеек хеш-таблицы, чтобы было видно к какому ключу относится значение(элемент) и как они там расположены?
Например:

[image: По такому типу]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно, это делается примерно так:

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_set>

int main()
{
    std::unordered_map<size_t, size_t> map;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < 500; ++i)
        map.emplace(i, i);
    for(size_t i = 0; i < map.bucket_count(); i++)
    {
        if(map.cbegin(i) == map.cend(i))
            continue;
        std::cout << "Bucket for keys {";
        std::unordered_set<size_t> processedKeys;
        for(auto it = map.cbegin(i); it != map.cend(i); ++it)
        {
            auto key = it->first;
            if(processedKeys.emplace(key).second)
                std::cout << key << ",";
        }
        std::cout << "\b}: ";
        for(auto it = map.cbegin(i); it != map.cend(i); ++it)
            std::cout << it->second << " ";
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}
```